# dotnet run with Mono Fails for .NETFramework 4.5.1

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-web-api, mono, asp.net-core

I am attempting to run my WebApi application on Linux using `.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1` (net451). The basic examples run fine when I use yeoman to create the WebApi project. However, my bigger project which uses .NETFramework 4.5.1 fails on the actual run.

The version of Mono I am using is 4.2.3 on both OSX and Linux (Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS). I may try to go to an unstable channel next, but I'm hoping I don't have to and that there's some way I can lose the `System.Diagnostics` dependency which appears to cause this (though I don't bring that package in directly).

I do not have this issue when I use dnx451 which I was using previously. I have been attempting to change over to the new tooling which is why I went down this path in the first place.

```
$ dotnet run
Project MyProject.Models (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Project MyProject.Api (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Stacktrace:
* Assertion at metadata.c:1017, condition `idx >= 0' not met
  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.get_trace (System.Exception,int,bool) <IL 0x0000f, 0xffffffff>
  at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace..ctor (System.Exception,int,bool) [0x0002e] in /private/tmp/mono20160330-58397-jmwbb9/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics/StackTrace.cs:129
  at System.Exception.get_StackTrace () [0x0001f] in /private/tmp/mono20160330-58397-jmwbb9/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/corlib/System/Exception.cs:202
  at System.Exception.ToString () [0x0007f] in /private/tmp/mono20160330-58397-jmwbb9/mono-4.2.3/mcs/class/corlib/System/Exception.cs:276
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_object__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00058, 0xffffffff>
Native stacktrace:
    0   mono                                0x0000000103463975 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 271
    1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff8cc2552a _sigtramp + 26
    2   ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
    3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff915ac6e7 abort + 129
    4   mono                                0x00000001035c79be monoeg_g_log + 0
    5   mono                                0x00000001035c7943 monoeg_g_logv + 83
    6   mono                                0x00000001035c7ae8 monoeg_assertion_message + 143
    7   mono                                0x0000000103509ab6 mono_metadata_decode_row + 233
    8   mono                                0x00000001034d881d get_docinfo + 61
    9   mono                                0x00000001034d832a mono_ppdb_lookup_location + 155
    10  mono                                0x000000010352047e mono_debug_lookup_source_location + 130
    11  mono                                0x00000001034611a1 ves_icall_get_trace + 482
    12  ???                                 0x00000001077f30e5 0x0 + 4420743397
    13  mono                                0x00000001033d68ca mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1463
    14  mono                                0x0000000103553c97 mono_runtime_invoke + 110
    15  mono                                0x0000000103558e63 mono_print_unhandled_exception + 176
    16  mono                                0x0000000103462be3 mono_handle_exception_internal + 3312
    17  mono                                0x0000000103461eef mono_handle_exception + 24
    18  mono                                0x00000001034b1267 mono_amd64_throw_exception + 113
    19  ???                                 0x0000000103987607 0x0 + 4355290631
    20  ???                                 0x0000000103be8f33 0x0 + 4357787443
    21  mono                                0x00000001033d68ca mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1463
    22  mono                                0x0000000103553c97 mono_runtime_invoke + 110
    23  mono                                0x0000000103558915 mono_runtime_exec_main + 379
    24  mono                                0x0000000103439800 mono_main + 6785
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff98ec15ad start + 1
Debug info from gdb:
(lldb) command source -s 0 '/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.6WMaVv'
Executing commands in '/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.6WMaVv'.
(lldb) process attach --pid 24146
Process 24146 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x45e53, 0x00007fff8ba79582 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8ba79582 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4:
->  0x7fff8ba79582 <+10>: jae    0x7fff8ba7958c            ; <+20>
    0x7fff8ba79584 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff8ba79587 <+15>: jmp    0x7fff8ba737f2            ; cerror
    0x7fff8ba7958c <+20>: retq   
Executable module set to "/usr/local/bin/mono".
Architecture set to: x86_64h-apple-macosx.
(lldb) thread list
Process 24146 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x45e53, 0x00007fff8ba79582 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  thread #2: tid = 0x45e55, 0x00007fff8ba78db6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
  thread #3: tid = 0x45e56, 0x00007fff8ba72fae libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
  thread #4: tid = 0x45e57, 0x00007fff8ba795e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
  thread #5: tid = 0x45e58, 0x00007fff8ba79efa libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent_qos + 10, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager'
  thread #6: tid = 0x45e59, 0x00007fff8ba795e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
(lldb) thread backtrace all
* thread #1: tid = 0x45e53, 0x00007fff8ba79582 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff8ba79582 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000103463a0b mono`mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 421
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8cc2552a libsystem_platform.dylib`_sigtramp + 26
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8ba78f07 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 11
    frame #4: 0x00007fff93e784ec libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
    frame #5: 0x00007fff915ac6e7 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 129
    frame #6: 0x00000001035c79be mono`monoeg_log_default_handler + 105
    frame #7: 0x00000001035c7943 mono`monoeg_g_logv + 83
    frame #8: 0x00000001035c7ae8 mono`monoeg_assertion_message + 143
    frame #9: 0x0000000103509ab6 mono`mono_metadata_decode_row + 233
    frame #10: 0x00000001034d881d mono`get_docinfo + 61
    frame #11: 0x00000001034d832a mono`mono_ppdb_lookup_location + 155
    frame #12: 0x000000010352047e mono`mono_debug_lookup_source_location + 130
    frame #13: 0x00000001034611a1 mono`ves_icall_get_trace + 482
    frame #14: 0x00000001077f30e5
    frame #15: 0x00000001033d68ca mono`mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1463
    frame #16: 0x0000000103553c97 mono`mono_runtime_invoke + 110
    frame #17: 0x0000000103558e63 mono`mono_print_unhandled_exception + 176
    frame #18: 0x0000000103462be3 mono`mono_handle_exception_internal + 3312
    frame #19: 0x0000000103461eef mono`mono_handle_exception + 24
    frame #20: 0x00000001034b1267 mono`mono_amd64_throw_exception + 113
    frame #21: 0x0000000103987607
    frame #22: 0x0000000103be8f33
    frame #23: 0x00000001033d68ca mono`mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1463
    frame #24: 0x0000000103553c97 mono`mono_runtime_invoke + 110
    frame #25: 0x0000000103558915 mono`mono_runtime_exec_main + 379
    frame #26: 0x0000000103439800 mono`mono_main + 6785
    frame #27: 0x00007fff98ec15ad libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #28: 0x00007fff98ec15ad libdyld.dylib`start + 1
  thread #2: tid = 0x45e55, 0x00007fff8ba78db6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8ba78db6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff93e76728 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 767
    frame #2: 0x000000010359e811 mono`thread_func + 273
    frame #3: 0x00007fff93e7599d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #4: 0x00007fff93e7591a libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 168
    frame #5: 0x00007fff93e73351 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #3: tid = 0x45e56, 0x00007fff8ba72fae libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8ba72fae libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001035bb3dc mono`mono_sem_wait + 29
    frame #2: 0x0000000103551fa4 mono`finalizer_thread + 124
    frame #3: 0x0000000103533ed1 mono`start_wrapper + 410
    frame #4: 0x00000001035c1bf9 mono`inner_start_thread + 197
    frame #5: 0x00007fff93e7599d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #6: 0x00007fff93e7591a libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 168
    frame #7: 0x00007fff93e73351 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #4: tid = 0x45e57, 0x00007fff8ba795e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8ba795e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff93e75578 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1283
    frame #2: 0x00007fff93e73341 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
  thread #5: tid = 0x45e58, 0x00007fff8ba79efa libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent_qos + 10, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8ba79efa libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent_qos + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8cace165 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8cacddcd libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 52
  thread #6: tid = 0x45e59, 0x00007fff8ba795e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8ba795e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff93e75578 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1283
    frame #2: 0x00007fff93e73341 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
(lldb) detach
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
Process 24146 detached
(lldb) quit
```

Comment: It appears that exception is somewhere else, and when something (logger?) calls ToString on that exception - this new exception occurs. I saw this error before when I deployed _debug_ versions of my dlls compiled with .NET to mono. Do you also run debug versions? If yes - try to compile in release mode and try again.

Comment: things like `* Assertion at metadata.c:1017, condition 'idx >= 0' not met` are almost always mono bugs, please report them appropiately to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Downgrade to 4.5 please.

Comment: @LexLi I cannot downgrade to 4.5 because EF 3.0.0-rc1-final (which I use) does not support 4.5.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Mono. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41233. They say you need to run Release to work around it.

Comment: @Pawel - Thanks! If you want to put that as an answer, I will accept it. Good find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Mono - [here](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41233) is a bug report which happen to contain a workaround